# OpenZepplin simple crowdsale - can't buy tokens

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin, openzeppelin-contracts

I have a very simple OpenZepplin (v2.5.1) crowdsale contract deployed on Rinkeby Testnet. But when I try to buy tokens it fails with `SafeERC20: low-level call failed` Why?

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.5;

import '@openzeppelin/contracts/crowdsale/Crowdsale.sol';
import '@openzeppelin/contracts/crowdsale/emission/AllowanceCrowdsale.sol';
import '@openzeppelin/contracts/crowdsale/validation/TimedCrowdsale.sol';
import '@openzeppelin/contracts/crowdsale/distribution/PostDeliveryCrowdsale.sol';
import '@openzeppelin/contracts/crowdsale/price/IncreasingPriceCrowdsale.sol';

contract MyCrowdsale is Crowdsale, TimedCrowdsale, AllowanceCrowdsale, PostDeliveryCrowdsale, IncreasingPriceCrowdsale {
    constructor(
        uint256 openingTime,
        uint256 closingTime,
        uint256 initialRate,
        uint256 finalRate,
        address payable wallet,
        IERC20 token
    )
    public
    Crowdsale(initialRate, wallet, token)
    TimedCrowdsale(openingTime, closingTime)
    IncreasingPriceCrowdsale(initialRate, finalRate)
    AllowanceCrowdsale(wallet)
    PostDeliveryCrowdsale()
    {

    }
}
```

It's deployed here: https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xd2a5f2ab4d0371b615663caf3213e20f945786e8#code

I have a feeling this has something to do with AllowanceCrowdsale, however I believe I already granted the contract allowance to sell the token, since `remainingTokens()` returns the correct amount of tokens for sale (prior to approving the allowance it returned 0).

You can easily test with the link above, using web3 on etherscan:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your token smartcontract is paused. Unpause it and repeat https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/token/0x327c24a16e028d5612b535a01f3d56d5f896cc2d#writeProxyContract

[image: pic]

Comment: Yup that was it. Just figured it out using Tenderly debugging features.